# silverlight and sharepoint restored site

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint

well i had a site in sharepoint with silverlight web parts, they all woked fine until i restored that site in another server, and now silverlight web parts are blank but show the silverlight menu, i tested silverlight in the same server in another sharepoint site and it worked fine, also i checked the web.config all looks ok, what could be wrong?

im working with iis 7 and win server 2008 and it works ok with normal sharepoint site but not this restored site =/

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the .XAP MIME type to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see if Silverlight can load all its assets? Images, xap files, etc.
You can use a tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

well this sharepoint site can load a image slide show made in silverlight as shown in http://www.wssdemo.com/Blog/archive/tags/Silverlight/default.aspx

but it cant load xap files =/